# Why am I getting Action not found when the code does not reference that action?

Tags: java, playframework

I changed the workflow of my application, which removed 4 actions that had previously been used.

I changed so that I no longer have a creditcardsaved, achsaved, and a couple other actions.

In my log files I get the error

```
"payment.creditcardsaved action not found"
```

The other 3 actions have not logged the same problem.  I have searched through my project, and I'm not referencing the creditcardsaved action anywhere.   I do still render that template, but I render it directly with renderTemplate("Payment/CreditCardSaved.html", args);

Previously there was a method in the controller

```
public static void creditcardsaved() {}
```

the save method `public static void SaveCreditCard` saved the payment then called the creditcardsaved() action.  There was no reference to the action from any view.

I no longer wanted the separate action to creditcardsaved(), I didn't want it showing up in the url.

So instead of calling it at the end of the SaveCreditCard method, I changed to renderTemplate("Payment/CreditCardSaved.html", args);

The output on the screen would match what it did before, but the url should be SaveCreditCard.  I also deleted the method creditcardsaved(), so it could not accidentally be called from anywhere.

The error full stack trace for the error is.

```
ERROR play - 

@67bi2d4oj
payment.creditcardsaved action not found

Action not found
Action payment.creditcardsaved could not be found. Error raised is No method public static void creditcardsaved() was found in class controllers.payment

play.exceptions.ActionNotFoundException: Action payment.creditcardsaved not found
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.getActionMethod(ActionInvoker.java:447)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:76)
    at play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.execute(ServletWrapper.java:472)
    at play.Invoker$Invocation.run(Invoker.java:187)
    at play.server.ServletWrapper$ServletInvocation.run(ServletWrapper.java:463)
    at play.Invoker.invokeInThread(Invoker.java:61)
    at play.server.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:113)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:179)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:445)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:301)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:275)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:639)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1772)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1563)
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: No method public static void creditcardsaved() was found in class controllers.payment
    ... 32 more
```

Comment: Removed an action?  You mean a method on your controller?  This question needs more details to be answered well.  What did you start with?  What did you do?  What did you expect?  What was the exact error message, and the line it died on?

Answer (score 2):

Check your route file. You might forget to delete the actions from it.

Comment: Then do play clean before you run it. It may solve some problems also. Play incremental compilation has some problems I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that none of your views reference creditcardsaved() either.  Look for tags like @{payment.creditcardsaved()}.  Also, one thing Play is very good at is returning helpful error messages in the browser.  If you could find which page this is failing for it will point you in the right direction.  If you still need help, post that info too.